# Content Negotiation - xml for a class is not returning a value

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-web-api

The api I'm working on allows a consumer to return json or xml.

If the user selects json then and if ChildItems is null, it returns null.
If the user selects xml, then nothing comes back at all. Shouldn't there be something with no values?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the child items.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The child items.</value>
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public List<ChildItem> ChildItems { get; set; }
```

Comment: Depends on whether you are using `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer`.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_media_type_formatter): *XML formatting is provided by the `XmlMediaTypeFormatter class`. By default, `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` uses the `DataContractSerializer` class to perform serialization.*  Do you know which you are using?

Comment: A list should always come back as a null if not initialize.  So is the parent class null?